# BigQuery - Find the last preceeding value before a specific one

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a list of values

my_list=['S', 'S', 'S', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'L', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'L']

When going through the list from left to right, each time I get an 'L', I need to find the last previous value which is not an 'L'

I am expecting

('L','S')
('L','S')
('L','S')
('L','B')
('L','D')

I tried

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT ['S', 'S', 'S', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'L', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'L'] AS elements
),
element_pairs AS (
  SELECT
    element,
    LEAD(element) OVER (ORDER BY OFFSET) AS next_element,
    LAG(element) OVER (ORDER BY OFFSET) AS prev_element
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      element,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS OFFSET
    FROM 
      data,
      UNNEST(elements) AS element
  )
)
SELECT
  'L' AS L,
  prev_element AS preceding_value
FROM
  element_pairs
WHERE
  next_element = 'L';
```

but obtaining
('L','S')
('L','S')
('L','L')
('L','B')
('L','D')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below approach

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT ['S', 'S', 'S', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'L', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'L'] AS elements
)
SELECT L, SPLIT(segment)[OFFSET(0)] AS preceding_value
FROM data, 
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(ARRAY_TO_STRING(elements, ','), r"(.(?:,L)+)")) segment WITH OFFSET AS a,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(segment, r'L')) AS L
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to have all preceding values, as an array for every element, remove 'L' from the array reverse array and take the first element as the preceding value.

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT ['S', 'S', 'S', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'L', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'L'] AS elements
),
element_pairs AS (
  SELECT
    element,
    ARRAY_AGG(element) OVER (ORDER BY OFFSET ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS preceding_elements
  FROM (
    SELECT element,ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS OFFSET
    FROM 
      data,UNNEST(elements) AS element))

  SELECT element AS L, last_non_L_preceding FROM
 (SELECT element,
    ARRAY_REVERSE(ARRAY(SELECT x FROM UNNEST(preceding_elements) AS x WHERE x != 'L'))[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS last_non_L_preceding
  FROM element_pairs) WHERE element = 'L';
```